# isset for form builder

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, formbuilder

I am using form builder and I share one form for edit and crete page so there are some variables I don't want to use.
I know that:

```
{!! Form::text('name', isset($admin_link->name) ? $admin_link->name : null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

would work but I do not consider it the best way. Is there any way to use something else like isset for form builder?

Comment: why not: `{!! Form::text('name', $admin_link->name ?? null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}`

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about this operator really, seems very useful :) Event thougt I did it another way that is special for form builder

Answer (score 0):

I sent the model to the blade with values what caused autocomplete of the input what is probably what I have been looking for:

```
 {!! Form::model( $admin_link, ['route' => ['admin.links.update', $admin_link->id], 'method' => 'post', 'class' => 'main_link_form']) !!}
```